# Daily Average for 1 Week

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am attempting to get the daily averages in the query below, for each day in a 1 week period.

```
SELECT AVG(`Carbs`) As Carbs, AVG(`Sugar`) As Sugar, AVG(`Units`) As Units,
DATE_FORMAT(`TrackedOn`, '%m/%d/%Y') As Date
FROM `Tracking`
WHERE `TrackedOn` BETWEEN ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND NOW()
```

However, it is only returning me 1 days worth of averages (but I think it's averaging everything in that 1 week, and only displaying the first day)

Can you help me achieve this?

Here is some dummy data, with the table structure:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `Tracking`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Tracking`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tracking` (
  `TrackID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `TrackType` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Carbs` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,
  `Sugar` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,
  `Units` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,
  `TrackedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  `TrackLocation` geometry NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TrackID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Tracking`
--

INSERT INTO `Tracking` (`TrackID`, `UserID`, `TrackType`, `Carbs`, `Sugar`, `Units`, `TrackedOn`, `TrackLocation`) VALUES
(1, 3, 1, 36.000, 217.000, 9.343, '2013-08-06 17:38:37', ''),
(2, 3, 1, 36.000, 316.000, 12.171, '2013-08-06 17:40:23', ''),
(3, 3, 4, 12.000, 316.000, 7.671, '2013-08-06 17:42:24', ''),
(4, 3, 5, 0.000, 316.000, 6.171, '2013-08-06 18:01:53', ''),
(5, 3, 5, 0.000, 317.000, 6.200, '2013-08-07 08:25:06', ''),
(6, 3, 2, 89.000, 317.000, 21.033, '2013-08-07 08:25:13', ''),
(7, 3, 5, 0.000, 317.000, 6.200, '2013-08-07 08:27:19', ''),
(8, 3, 3, 82.000, 168.000, 12.193, '2013-08-07 08:27:31', ''),
(9, 1, 3, 86.000, 217.000, 13.000, '2013-08-07 08:28:08', ''),
(10, 3, 5, 0.000, 317.000, 6.200, '2013-08-07 09:13:39', '');
```

My goal is to return the daily averages of `Carbs`, `Sugar`, `Units` in between Today (NOW()) and 7 Days ago.

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY` the day. Try adding `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`TrackedOn`, '%m/%d/%Y')` to the end of your query.

Comment: Yeah, just had a dur moment, tried it before your comment, and it worked...  I need some more dummy data before I can confirm though, so give me just a bit.  Post this as an answer though ok?

Comment: Confirmed, works as expected.  Thanks Ed.  If you just post that as an answer, I'll get it accepted

Comment: Ed?  Wanna post as an answer?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder o7th! I meant to do that before but forgot. I've posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(TrackedOn, '%m/%d/%Y')` to the end of your query, and MySQL will summarize everything by day:

```
SELECT AVG(`Carbs`) As Carbs, AVG(`Sugar`) As Sugar, AVG(`Units`) As Units,
DATE_FORMAT(`TrackedOn`, '%m/%d/%Y') As Date
FROM `Tracking`
WHERE `TrackedOn` BETWEEN ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(TrackedOn, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track. Since `avg()` is an aggregate function it will compute the value and shown as one. If you would like to get avg for each day. you need to apply a `group by` clause.
Have a look [here](http://www.thunderstone.com/site/texisman/summarizing_values.html).

Here you can try like:

```
SELECT AVG(`Carbs`) As Carbs, AVG(`Sugar`) As Sugar, AVG(`Units`) As Units,
DATE_FORMAT(`TrackedOn`, '%m/%d/%Y') As Dates
FROM `Tracking`
WHERE `TrackedOn` BETWEEN ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY Dates;
```